# Background-size: cover is cutting off my image on larger screens

Tags: css, background-image

I have site that I'm laying out. It's basically Header, Content and Footer all 100% width.
I want to have the background image fill the screen in the content section. I achieved this with the CSS3 background-size:cover. The only problem when Im scaling up to a screen that is 2560px the image gets cut off. Is there a way to work around this so that doesn't happen?

My CSS

```
#maincontentcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../images/sandpiperBG.jpg);
    background-position:center center; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    -moz-background-size:cover; 
    -webkit-background-size:cover; 
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=responsive+background+image

Comment: If you want the image to always fill the screen "cover" is the way to go, but the browser may need to crop it in order to do that and  preserve the aspect ratio. Can you post a link to a demo page?

Comment: here is a link thanks http://www.gregtaylordesignstudio.com/sandpiperbeach/responsive.html

Answer (score 4):

```
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Will fix it, but the images will become stretched/squashed because you have a fixed height but a variable width.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the suggestion, but that's not going to work for me because of the stretching

Comment: @Greg Then you are left with the option of using media queries. See http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ . You can either detect screen width and vary the height of the element to allow more space for the image, or you can load a different size image that matches the aspect ratio of the screen it is being viewed on. The current fixed height means the container aspect ratio is but you're trying to fit an image with a fixed aspect ratio inside it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get background image as full, try this instead:

```
background-size: contain;
```